# conservative and path independent difference

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, curl

suppose that we have a function $F(x,y)=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ if we calculate $curlF$ we understand that $curlF=0$ ( computing $curlF$ is not my question). now the book has written that because the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ so we can't conclude that $F$ is conservative. but F is path independent.

first question: so I concluded that if $curlF=0$ and $F$ is simply connected then $F$ is conservative but if $curlF=0$ and $F$ is not simply connected (like this example) then $F$ is path-independent. is that correct?

second question: what is the difference between conservative and path-independent?

Comment: Actually, $F$ is not path independent : compute $\int F \cdot dr $ from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$, first on $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, then on $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. You will see that both integrals do not match : $F$ is not path independent per se.

Comment: As for the definitions, conservative means there exists a function $\phi$ such that $F = \text{grad}\ \phi$. The generalization of this notion is exact differential forms. The curl being zero generalizes to the notion of closed differential form. The notion that a conservative field has zero curl is a special case of DeRham cohomology. As you say, [curl being zero implies the field being conservative] if and only if the domain is simply connected.